# Attach Select2 with onClick() of jQuery

Tags: jquery, onclick, jquery-select2

I am trying to attach [Select2](https://select2.org) with onClick() of jQuery. My HTML code is `<td class="volunteer" id="47">Bob SMith and admin</td>`. My jQuery code is like below.

```
(function($) {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".volunteer").on("click", function () {            
        $(this).html(`<select class="js-example-basic-multiple" name="states[]" multiple="multiple">
                <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
                <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
            </select>`);
        });
        $('.js-example-basic-multiple').select2();
    });
})(jQuery)
```

But this is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues preventing the select from loading.

1. The initialisation of select2 is outside of the click event, it therefore occurs when the page loads before the select element exists. This must occur after the select has been added to the DOM.

   ```js
   $('.js-example-basic-multiple').select2();
   ```
2. The click event is registered on the class 'volunteer' and any clicks on the cell execute this function, even after the select is loaded. This causes the select to reload when you try and select an option, causing the option to be lost. To resolve this you could check if the select has already been loaded.

   ```js
   if(!$(this).has("select").length) {
   ```

```js
(function($) {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var state = "";
    $(".volunteer").on("click", function(event) {
        // Check if select is already loaded
      if(!$(this).has("select").length) {
        // Populate select element
        $(this).html(`<select class="js-example-basic-multiple" name="states[]" multiple="multiple">
            <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
            <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
            </select>`);      
              
        // Initialise select2
        $(this).children("select").select2();
      }
    });
  });
})(jQuery)
```

```css
.js-example-basic-multiple {
  width: 200px;  
}

thead{
    font-weight: bold;
}

table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>Table Header 1</td>
      <td>Table Header 2</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="volunteer" id="47">Click Me</td>
      <td class=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="volunteer" id="48">Click Me</td>
      <td class=""></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks @Chris C. I am using this HTML `<td class="volunteer" id="47">Bob SMith and admin</td>`. I need to attach `Select2` with it. 
But you are attaching `Select2` with another element `<div id='selectContainer'></div>`. Thanks.

Comment: @abuabu . I've made some updates to the answer based on the information you've provided about it being in a td element

Comment: If it's useful, the following JS Fiddle extends this answer to store the selected value for each row into an array and restore the value if the select is reopened https://jsfiddle.net/etof2u0L/

Comment: Thanks @Chris C. Your JS Fiddle is exactly what I was looking for. `let selectEle = cellEle.children("select").select2();` why did you initialize select2 and how did you initialize select2 ? Could you please explain more ?

Comment: @abuabu The structure of the HTML once the select is added looks like `<td><select></select></td>`. The line `let selectEle = cellEle.children("select").select2();` takes the element for the cell `td` which was identified earlier and stored in the variable `cellEle`. It then uses the jQuery method `.children("select")` to identify a `select` element which is a child, it then initialises select2 on this select element.

Comment: Thanks @Chris C. I made another post  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70419682/jquery-select2-with-wordpress

Comment: Could you please help me in this post ?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70460242/send-receive-parameters-of-ajax-in-select2