# jQuery select2 with WordPress

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, jquery-select2

I am working with jQuery [select2](https://select2.org) inside WordPress.

I have a HTML table like this.

[image]

I need here if user clicks on `Bob SMith and admin` it will convert to a `select2` dropdown with multiple select.

But when I click on it, it looks like below

[image]

and if I click again, the dropdown looks like this.

[image]

When I click on any values, it looks like below

[image]

My jQuery code is like below

```
(function($) {
  var states = [];
  
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".volunteer").on("click", function(event) {
      // Check if select is already loaded
      if (!$(this).has("select").length) {
        var cellEle = $(this);
        var cellId = this.id;

        // Populate select element
        cellEle.html(`<select class="js-example-basic-multiple" multiple="multiple">
            <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
            <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
            </select>`);

        // Initialise select2
        let selectEle = cellEle.children("select").select2();
        
        if(states[cellId]){
            // preselect existing value
          selectEle.val(states[cellId]);
          selectEle.trigger('change'); 
        }

        selectEle.on("select2:close", function(event) {
          // Get selected value
          selectedValue = selectEle.select2('data')[0]['text'];

          // Update array          
          states[cellId] = selectedValue.id;
          
          // Destroy select2
          selectEle.select2('destroy');
          
          // Change html to just show the value
          cellEle.html(selectedValue.id);
        });
      }
    });
  });
})(jQuery)
```

My HTML code is like below

```
<td class="volunteer" id="47">Bob SMith and admin</td>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

##### Click Twice

The first click on the cell initialises select2, the second click then tells select2 to display the dropdown. To only require a single click you can call the open method described at https://select2.org/programmatic-control/methods after select2 is initialized.

```js
// Initialise select2
let selectEle = cellEle.children("select").select2();
// Open the select2 dropdown
selectEle.select2('open');
```

##### Replace Select

When clicking on a value select2 is being destroyed, the `.html()` call should replace the select with the selected value, however it does not function correctly as the `id` property doesn't exist on the stored value, this is causing the cell to revert to a normal select.

The code which handles the `"select2:close"` event contains the line `selectedValue = selectEle.select2('data')[0]['text'];` which places the text of a just the first selected value `[0]` into the variable `selectedValue`. After this the HTML of the cell is updated using `cellEle.html(selectedValue.id);`, but at this point `selectedValue` contains just the text (e.g. "Alabama") so there is no `.id` property. To resolve this both the ID and Text could be stored in the array, then used where needed, for example:

```js
// Store the id and text of all selected values in the array
selectedValue = selectEle.select2('data').map(function(value) {
  return { id: value.id, text: value.text }; 
});

// Get an array of IDs for the selected values (for preselecting values when select2 loads)
selectEle.val(states[cellId].map(function(value) { return value.id })).trigger('change');

// Get a comma separated string of the selected values (for populating the text in the cell)
cellEle.html(states[cellId].map(function(value) { return value.text; }).join(','));
```

**Multi Select Mode** -
An example which allows multiple selections is https://jsfiddle.net/aqgbxz1d/ and also incorporated into this answer below. This seems to be the desired mode based on the `multiple="multiple"` property in the question.

The example is updated to no longer use the `select2:close` event. Instead it uses the `change` event to store value changes, and a second `click` event handler on the document to destroy the select2 dropdown(s) when the user clicks somewhere else on the page. This seems like a better approach given what you are trying to achieve as it leaves the select open for multiple values to be selected.

**Single Select Mode** -
From the comments it seems single select mode may be required. An example which allows just a single selection is https://jsfiddle.net/9jcnwbt2/1/. If single select mode is required, then you would need to:

- Remove the multiple attribute `multiple="multiple"`
- add a blank option `<option></option>`
- You could also replicate replicate the code from the document click event which destroys select2 and updates the HTML into the change event.

```js
(function ($) {
  var states = [];

  $(document).ready(function () {
    $(".volunteer").on("click", function (e) {
      // Check if select is already loaded
      if (!$(this).has("select").length) {
        var cellEle = $(this);
        var cellId = this.id;

        // Populate select element
        cellEle.html(`<select class="js-example-basic" multiple="multiple">
                    <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
                    <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
                    </select>`);

        // Initialise select2
        let selectEle = cellEle.children("select").select2({placeholder: "Select a value"});

        // Open the select dropdown so user doesn't have to click twice
        selectEle.select2('open');

        // Check if there is an existing value for this cell
        if (states[cellId]) {
          // preselect existing value
          selectEle.val(states[cellId].map(function (value) {
            return value.id
          })).trigger('change');
        }

        // Attach event handler to store value changes
        selectEle.on('change', function (e) {

          // Get selected values
          selectedValues = $(this).select2('data');

          // Update the states array with id and text of selected 
          // values. The id is needed to restore the values if select2
          // is reloaded on this cell. The text is required to generate
          // the replacement text shown in the cell
          states[cellId] = selectedValues.map(function (value) {
            return {
              id: value.id,
              text: value.text
            };
          });
        });
      }

      // Don't propagate the event
      // This prevents this document click handler from executing which would
      // remove select2 by calling destroy
      e.stopPropagation();
    });
  });

  // Attach event handler to document to capture any clicks
  // This will be triggered for all clicks on the page, except those 
  // captured by the method described above this prevents this firing
  // with e.stopPropagation()
  // Which this is called select2 on any cells must be destoryed and their 
  // text value populated
  $(document).on('click', function (e) {
    // Loop through all select2 elements
    $('.js-example-basic').each(function (idx) {
      // Get the ID of the cell that's been selected
      let cellId = $(this).parent().attr('id');

      // Destroy select2 on this element
      $(this).select2('destroy');

      // Change html on the parent element (td) to just show the value
      if(states[cellId] && states[cellId].length > 0){
        $(this).parent().html(states[cellId].map(function (value) {
          return value.text;
        }).join(','));
      } else {
        $(this).parent().html("Select a value...")
      }
    });
  });

})(jQuery)
```

```css
.js-example-basic {
  width: 200px;  
}

thead{
    font-weight: bold;
}

table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

tr {
  height: 36px;
}

td {
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>Table Header 1</td>
      <td>Table Header 2</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="volunteer" id="47">Select a value...</td>
      <td class=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="volunteer" id="48">Select a value...</td>
      <td class=""></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks @Chris C. Actually I need a pre populated multiple value select able drop-down like this one https://i.stack.imgur.com/yxlTK.png.

Comment: The screenshot appears to show select2 in single select mode, rather than multiselect which was enabled in the example code with `multiple="multiple"`. These modes are shown at https://select2.org/getting-started/basic-usage. 
I've updated the answer with a bug fix for selecting no value and with an example for single select.

Comment: @abuabu Happy to help. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.

Comment: Thanks @Chris C. I made accepted answer.

Comment: Could you please help me in this post ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71043039/tooltip-is-not-closing-with-select2