# Send & Receive parameters of AJAX in Select2

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress, jquery-select2

How to Send parameters of AJAX in [Select2](https://select2.org) and Receive in PHP ?

I am trying to send parameters is like below.

```
     let element_id = event.target.id;
     let selectEle = cellEle.children("select").select2({
          ajax: {
            url: "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
            dataType: 'json',
            data: function (element_id) {
                 return { 
                    q: element_id,
                    action: 'get_data'
                 };
             },
            type: "post",
            processResults: function(data) {                             
              console.log(data);
            }
          }
        });
```

I am trying to receive parameters like below.

```
function get_data()
{
    echo json_encode($_POST['q']);
    die;
}
```

I am getting result `null`.

[image]

Comment: $_POST['q'] is for form data ... your data should be like this then : "q="+element_id+"&action=get_data";

Comment: Thanks @Shlomtzion. But I am sending data as POST. How can I receive parameter value in PHP ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name `element_id` is used for both a varaible declared on the first line `let element_id = event.target.id;` and as the name of the parameter the data function uses `data: function (element_id) {`.

When the data function is called select2 will place the parameters of select2 in `element_id` scoped to the function, so it'll have variables like `_type` set to 'query' and `term` set to the search term (if one has been enetered). This is described in more detail at https://select2.org/data-sources/ajax#request-parameters.

I would suggest adjusting the parameter name used for the data function. I've updated it to `params` in the example below to match the examples on the select2 site. The `element_id` variable set on the first line can then be used to pass the data.

```js
let element_id = event.target.id;
let selectEle = cellEle.children("select").select2({
  ajax: {
    url: "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
    dataType: 'json',
    data: function (params) {
         return { 
            q: element_id,
            action: 'get_data'
         };
     },
    type: "post",
    processResults: function(data) {                             
      console.log(data);
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks @Chris C. Could you please say anything about PHP side ?

Comment: As far as I'm aware the PHP side should be fine. It seems you are already able to access $_POST['action'], with this update to the JavaScript $_POST['q'] should have the value you are looking for